# how to add three columns to existing tables with particular schema

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to add three columns to all tables on database with default values for a particular 
schema,

```
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable  @command1 = N'ALTER TABLE ? ADD CompanyID Varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT 0'
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable1  @command2 = N'ALTER TABLE ? ADD TenantID Varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT 3'
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable2  @command3 = N'ALTER TABLE ? ADD ViewObjectID Varchar NOT NULL DEFAULT 0'
```

How can i mention the schema?

Comment: The whole table belongs to one schema only. What do you want to do?

Comment: I have different schemas on separate database, i want to add columns to tables with particular schema. say for sample tables with schema "CDA."

Comment: You should **always** specify an **explicit length** for any `VARCHAR` columns, variables, parameters! Otherwise you might run into unexpected and hard-to-find errors! Use `VARCHAR(50)` (or whatever makes sense) instead of just `VARCHAR` !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the @whereand parameter to restrict the tables used in the foreach sp. The where is used when selecting rows from the sysobjects table.

```
EXECUTE sp_MSforeachtable  
            @command1 = N'ALTER TABLE ? ADD CompanyID Varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0'  
          , @whereand = N'AND SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)  = ''CDA'' '
```

I peeked at [this article](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3441031/SQL-Server-Undocumented-Stored-Procedures-spMSforeachtable-and-spMSforeachdb.htm) and [grabbed the schema_name function from example D](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190324(v=sql.105).aspx)

<sup>notice I added the length on the varchar type as stated in the comments by [marc_s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13302/marc-s)</sup>